# WSO2 ESB: JAR file with callback handler not loading

Tags: wso2, esb, ws-security, rampart

I am trying to setup a proxy service that hides the security of a back end service, following the tutorial found [here](http://soasecurity.org/2012/11/05/how-to-invoke-secured-backend-service-using-wso2-esb/).
For the password callback handler I follow the instructions found [here](http://soasecurity.org/2010/02/07/how-to-create-a-password-callback-class/).
All pretty basic and straightforward.

I compiled the `PWCBHandler` class into a JAR file and put it in the esbhome\repository\components\lib folder together with all the JAR files from wss4j-1.6.15\lib.

I see no warnings or errors during startup of the ESB. However when I test the proxy service, I get the following error in the log:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error in obtaining a token
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
...
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Error in obtaining a token
    at org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.getToken(RampartUtil.java:779)
    at org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.getIssuedToken(RampartUtil.java:675)
...
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Cannot load password callback class: PWCBHandler
    at org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.getPasswordCB(RampartUtil.java:144)
    at org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.getPasswordCB(RampartUtil.java:118)
    at org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.getToken(RampartUtil.java:723)
...
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PWCBHandler
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PWCBHandler
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:200)
    at org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:163)
    at org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.getPasswordCB(RampartUtil.java:142)
    ... 28 more
[2014-06-16 15:56:23,103]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_CODE : 0
[2014-06-16 15:56:23,103]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_MESSAGE : Unexpected error during sending message out
[2014-06-16 15:56:23,103]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:170)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:69)
...
```

In other words, the ESB and Rampart know about the `PWCBHandler` class but it cannot load / access it.

At this point I have no ideas where to look further. Is there a way where I can check which JAR files were loaded during startup? What might prohibit the loading of the `PWCBHandler` JAR?

Thanks for your feedback,

Olivier

Comment: to check whether the jar file is loaded, you can start the server with osgi console (command: ./wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole). Once server completes loading, hit enter and you'll get the equinox osgi console. you can check the bundles with 'ss | grep <bundle_name>'. All equinox commands are valid here.

Comment: The `ss` command showed the JAR file was indeed not loading. No indication why. The output did gave me an idea, don't know why. I noticed all the `org.x.y` package entries and that was something I did not do. So added the callback class to 'my' package, recompiled and re-jarred the thing and now the bundle is listed at id 3.

Put on my todo list: dig into equinox...

Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer from Rajeev I got confirmation the class was not loading.

I recreated the JAR file with the class added to a package and after restarting the server a bundle for the JAR was created.
It looks like custom classes need to be added to a package for Carbon to create a bundle from it.

I know, I know, classes should always be added to a package, but I am not a Java hero and did not want to bother with the dirs and such.

Lessons learned! :)